# Thread safe function in java to count number of words in a sentences

Tags: java, thread-safety

I was interviewed and asked to write a function to count number of words in a sentence. The function should be thread safe.
Would the following method works for that?

```
public static synchronized int find(String str){

    int count=0;
    boolean word= false;

    char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
    for(int i =0;i<ch.length;i++){
        if(!(ch[i]==' ')){
            for(int j=i;j<ch.length;j++,i++){
                if(!(ch[j]==' ')){
                    word= true;
                    if(j==ch.length-1){
                        count++;
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    if(word){
                        count++;
                    }
                    word = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    return count;   
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to do anything out of the ordinary to make the function thread-safe; it doesn't access any shared resources. (Hopefully that wasn't the intention of the interview question, because I'd hate to ruin it for you.) By the way, see also [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Comment: You would almost have to *try* to make this thread-unsafe. (I say almost because someone who doesn't understand the distinction between local variables and class fields might make a static field for something here.)

Comment: While this function seems to work, you've most likely failed the interview. Your code is unnecessarily complex and highly bug-prone. The double loop was overkill, and the fact that the inner loop modifies `i` is highly confusing. `j` is redundant; whenever it's in use, it has the same value as `i`. Marking the method `synchronized` was unnecessary. This whole thing could have been solved in one line with a library call.

Comment: I was not not allowed to use library function. Still I used for string length.

Comment: I wonder if the purpose of the interview question was to use a divide-and-conquer approach so that you could use multiple cores to count the number of words? From the little info given, that would be my guess.

Comment: @user2357112 library calls like `String.split(regex)` are performance killers because of regular express compiling and calculating.

Answer (score 2):

If all your method's variables/instances are local, and the parameters are threadsafe, the method is threadsafe.

This would be my implementation (which has *no* local variables):

```
public static int countWords(String str) {
    return str.trim().split("\\s+").length;
}
```

The only object in play here is the String parameter. In java, a `String` is immutable and therefore threadsafe, so this implementation is threadsafe.

---

Note: By "local variables" I mean "variables that hold primitives or references to locally created objects".

Comment: "If your method only uses local variables, it is threadsafe." - kind of a misleading statement, there. If your local variable and some other thread's local variable refer to the same object, and you're both calling thread-unsafe methods on it at the same time, your code is not thread-safe.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson hmmm. It is correct. I've clarified in the answer. Basically, if the *instances* are local it doesn't matter if the methods are threadsafe

Comment: @user2357112 see edit to answer. "local variables" *can't* refer to the same object as other threads - they are created within the method.

Comment: @Bohemian: I don't think your answer makes sense after your edits. If your method "has *no* local variables", that can only mean that you're not considering parameters to be local variables -- in which case your method isn't an example of one that "only uses local variables".

Comment: You should note that `String`'s immutability is essential to the thread safety here.

Comment: @ruakh all of my variables are local. all zero of them. I have changed the wording slightly to allow for zero, but seriously we are just playing semantics here. the answer is "correct" as far as I am concerned. it's not a complicated concept - it shouldn't require a lot of complicated explanation.

Comment: @arshajii thank you for making a constructive comment

Comment: @Bohemian: I was pretty O.K. with your answer until you added the wrong statements. Your new final sentence improves the answer somewhat, but the immutability/thread-safety of the parameter is really the central point, whereas your current answer makes it seem like an afterthought.

Comment: Oh, wait -- now I understand why you got all snippy: you misunderstood my comment. I wasn't playing at the semantics of zero; I was just pointing out that your method *is* using a non-local variable, namely the parameter. Your code absolutely depends on the fact that `str` is threadsafety-friendly, which is why you can't treat that as an afterthought.

Comment: (Anyway, provisionally -1. If you decide to fix your answer, let me know.)